# API for Enterprise Architect configured on Version Control

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am unable to find a .Net API for Enterprise Architect configured on Version Control. I followed following links to search for the same, but was not able to find.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/projects_and_teams/usingversioncontrol.html

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/projects_and_teams/versioncontrol.html

Comment: What would you expect to be able to do? Setting it up? Do check in/out?

Comment: @RishvaPatel, whcih version control operation you would like to automate using C#?

Comment: @user3165438 I would like to do Undo Check Out using C# i.e. .Net API

Answer (score 1):

The .Net API for Enterprise Architect is a dll located in the EA program files folder: Interop.EA.dll

There are some version control related operations on [EA.Package](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/automation_and_scripting/package_2.html)

Comment: @Greet Bellekens 
Yes I tried those operations given in EA.Package but was not able get expected results. 
For example on trying the following code : 

Package package = r.GetPackageByGuid("{3184A315-07B7-4ad0-88F5-7D5618A34898}");

if (package.IsVersionControlled)
            {
                package.VersionControlCheckout();
            }
   
It gave an error: Could not find connection to version control provider.

But my package was not in offline mode.

Comment: @RishvaPatel That seems crucial information that you should definitely include in your question.

Comment: @RishvaPatel I agree with Geert, please add the specific problem to the question. The reason the question has been close-voted is that there's no code in it.